# CSV Should Return Strings, Not Bytes Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, zip

I am trying to read CSV files from a directory that is not in the same directory as my Python script.

Additionally the CSV files are stored in ZIP folders that have the exact same names (the only difference being one ends with .zip and the other is a .csv).

Currently I am using Python's `zipfile` and `csv` libraries to open and get the data from the files, however I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "write_pricing_data.py", line 13, in <module>
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

My code:

```
import os, csv
from zipfile import *

folder = r'D:/MarketData/forex'
localFiles = os.listdir(folder)

for file in localFiles:
    zipArchive = ZipFile(folder + '/' + file)

    with zipArchive.open(file[:-4] + '.csv') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')

        for row in reader:
            print(row[0])
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: have you opened the files in a text editor to make sure the contents are as you expect?

Comment: Yea, their pretty large, but still standard csv, comma delimiters and all.

Comment: it'd probably be helpful for you to post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Ok I updated my post.

Comment: Open this way instead: `with zipArchive.open(file[:-4] + '.csv', 'rt') as csvFile:`

Comment: It returns an error unfortunately: `RuntimeError: open() requires mode "r", "U", or "rU"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a kludge and I'm sure there's a better way (that just happens to elude me right now). If you don't have embedded new lines, then you can use:

```
import zipfile, csv

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('testing.csv.zip')
with zf.open('testing.csv', 'r') as fin:
    # Create a generator of decoded lines for input to csv.reader
    # (the csv module is only really happy with ASCII input anyway...)
    lines = (line.decode('ascii') for line in fin)
    for row in csv.reader(lines):
        print(row)
```