# Reading CSV file through Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm currently trying to read through a CSV file that is being provided through Flask-WTF(orms) and I continue to run into issues when trying to load it through `csv.DictReader` or `pandas`.

The file (a `FileStorage` object) is not actually being uploaded anywhere, and I am trying to grab the data within the CSV to use within my code.

This is how I'm trying to grab it now using `pandas`

```
f = form.upload.data
data = pandas.read_csv(f.stream)
logger.debug(data)
```

However this returned the error `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

When I tried grabbing it through `csv.reader` this way:

```
reader = csv.reader(f.read(), delimeter=',')

for row in reader:
    logger.debug(row)
```

I got this error instead: `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

I received a similar error when trying out `csv.DictReader` as well.

Has anyone tried to do anything similar to this, or know if this is even possible without uploading the file anywhere? I've looked around but I can't seem to find a proper solution.

For reference, my CSV file has a pretty basic format:

```
C1,C2
Data,Data
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269442/977593

Comment: @slackmart This is not a duplicate, can I provide an answer below?

Comment: Hey @AlxVallejo unfortunately I don't have enough privileges to reopen this question. Perhaps you could contact RaspberryLand13 folk  or post your answer as a comment.